# override just the arrowkey scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

So I'm creating a custom scroll box, because the standard html < select> box just isn't cutting it(I need two columns displayed, and couldn't find how to do this with a < select>). Anyways I have a scrollable table that is working JUST how I want it to. Except for up and down arrow keys trigger an overall scroll rather than selecting either the preceding or proceeding elements in the table.

html < select > with the appropriate binding of up and down
http://jsfiddle.net/a5YJK/

my custom select without appropriate up and down 
http://jsfiddle.net/8zgxA/3/

when I run

```
$('#wrap *').scroll(function(e){});
```

I can't differentiate between a mouse scroll and a up or down arrow. How do I differentiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for `e.keyCode` or `e.which` which would be absent for scroll events.

```
$(window).on('keyup scroll', function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode); //undefined for mouse scroll

    if(e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 40){
        //down arrow, scroll might occur, so prevent it or do whatever
    }
}); ​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/Q7KZ9/)

Comment: So if e.keyCode == undefined then it's not the up or down key?

Comment: @CynicalOptimist: Same way as in any window. `F12` or Right Click - Inspect element :)

Comment: haha thanks, ok how do I make this window specific? http://jsfiddle.net/8zgxA/7/ is not working like I want it to :(, only the scroll event is coming through.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table onfocus="focused(1)" onblur="focused(0)" onkeypress="selectnext(event)">
.
.
.
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentrow = 0;
var tablefocused;
function focused(a)
{
switch(a)
{
case 1:
tablefocused = 1;
break;
case 0:
tablefocused = 0;
break;
}
}
function selectnext(e)
e.stopPropagation();
{
if(tablefocused==1)
{
switch(e.keyCode)
{
case 38:
currentrow = currentrow-1;
this.childNodes[currentrow].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
$('tr').css('background', '');
break;
case 40:
currentrow = currentrow+1;
this.childNodes[currentrow].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
$('tr').css('background', '');
break;
}
}
}
</script>
```

I have left out some detail from this code, for example 'currentrow' should not go to -1, clicking on a row should change the value of currentrow to that row, e.t.c.

Oh and to prevent scrolling you use the stopPropagation() function to prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: Thanks for the stopPropagation() hint! Though this is a little too much javascript specific for me. Let me ponder it for a bit :D